# Java Shingle Pairs

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm having trouble with a program I'm working on to create shingle pairs from each sentence in a text file. Right now my code reads in a .txt file in Java and outputs each sentence in order. I want to store each sentence separately then take each sentence and create 2-character shingles of them, which would be stored in an array. An example of this would be taking the sentence “The quick brown fox” and turning it into {th, he, e ,  q, qu, ui, ic, ck, k ,  b, br, ro, ow, wn, n ,  f, fo, ox} so that all of the spaces in between the words would be accounted for. My goal is to simply take each sentence and create an array for each of them that holds the shingle pairs like in the example above. My problem is that I'm not sure how to go about this. I can’t seem to figure out how to take the sentences and store them separately, and I’m not sure how to create shingle pairs. I'm still very new to Java, and any help is very much appreciated. Here is my code so far:

```
//Takes .txt file as command-line input parameter
File file = new File(args[0]);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file)); 
int i=0;

//Reads in and outputs each line from the file
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
System.out.print(++i + " : " + scanner.nextLine() + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take pairs of characters from [0,1] to [last-1,last]

```
String[] result = new String[sentence.length() - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length() - 2; i++)
{
    result[i] = sentence.substring(i, i + 2);
}
```

If you nead, you may delete spaces with `trim()` after it this cycle.

Answer (score 0):

To split into sentences you can use pattern matching. Just define what is a valid sentene for your task. Here I assume a sentence is always ended with dot, question mark or exclamation mark; and the next sentence starts after one or more whitespaces

```
final Pattern sentencePattern = Pattern.compile("[\\.\\?!]+\\s+");
sentencePattern.splitAsStream(text).forEach(
        System.out::println //your code here
);
```